# $V = V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_3 \Leftrightarrow f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to solve the following problem.

> Let $V$ be a 3-dimensional complex vector space, and $V^{*}$ be a dual
> space of it. We denote the kernel of $f\in V^{*}$ by
> $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$. For $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in V^{*}$, we define
>
> $\begin{align} V_1 &= \mathrm{Ker}(f_1)\cap \mathrm{Ker}(f_2) \\ V_2
>  &=\mathrm{Ker}(f_2)\cap \mathrm{Ker}(f_3) \\ V_3 &= \mathrm{Ker}(f_3)
>  \cap \mathrm{Ker}(f_1)\end{align}\tag*{}$
>
> Prove that the following conditions (a) and (b) are equivalent.
>
> (a)$V$ is a direct sum of subspaces $V_1,V_2,V_3$.
>
> (b)$f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly independent.

**My attempt:**
I tried to prove (a) implies (b) first.
By assumption, for any $v\in V$, there exist unique elements $v_i\in V_i(i=1,2,3)$ such that $v=v_1+v_2+v_3$.

If $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly dependent, there exists $(c_1,c_2,c_3)\neq (0,0,0)$ such that
$c_1f_1(v)+c_2f_2(v)+c_3 f_3(v)=0$. Substituting $v=v_1+v_2+v_3$, we obtain $c_1f_1(v_2)+c_2f_2(v_3)+c_3 f_3(v_1)=0$.

... and I am stuck. I think we should prove that there are non-zero elements $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that $0=v_1+v_2+v_3$, but was unable to do so.

I would prefer a hint rather than a complete solution since I really wanna be able to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Try substituting each of $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ separately into the relation $c_1f_1 + c_2f_2 + c_3f_3 = 0$ and see what that tells you about $c_1,c_2,c_3$.

Also, generally speaking it's worth it to consider the analogous problem in $\mathbb R^3$. Geometrically it's possible to visualize $V_1,V_2,V_3$ as concrete linear subspaces. What do they look like? Do the pictures you can draw give you some ideas about how to prove the reverse implication?

Answer (score 0):

For a) implies b), show that no $V_i$ has dimension 3 and hence every $V_i$ has dimension 1. This allows you to pick appropriate $v_i's\neq 0$ that eliminate two out of the three constants.

Comment: Why does no $V_i$ having dimension 3 imply a dimension of $V_i$=1? Is it not possible to have a dimension of $0$ or $2$?

Comment: Actually, what you need to show is that each $V_i$ has at least one $v_i \neq 0$. The fact that each $V_i$ is one-dimensional is not relevant.